# nginx CentOS 7 can not reached via http

Tags: nginx, centos

nginx configured on vps but default index.html not reached by public ip or domain name via http

nginx config

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  domainname.com;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;

    location / {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default centos 7 firewall is blocking port 80

need edit next file

> /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml

add 80 port

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="80"/>
</zone>
```

reload firewall

> firewall-cmd --reload